# How can I use a VisualForce page to set a custom setting field?

Tags: visualforce, customsetting, configuration

I'm trying to create a VisualForce configuration page for my managed package. I have a hierarchal custom setting field for an authentication key which is needed to access a remote service. I can read this value with `"{!$Setup.prefix__Settings__c.prefix__Key__c}"`

however, if I try making an input field for it using

```
<apex:inputField value="{!$Setup.prefix__Settings__c.prefix__Key__c}"/>
```

it says that only sObjects work for inputField values.

I thought merge fields worked too...anyway, how can I let the user type in a key and save that value to the custom settings record? Also, would using a List custom setting be easier or better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set them via Apex controller. Here is some [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm#apex_methods_system_custom_settings)

So it would be something like this (for hierarchy settings):

Apex:

```
public String myValueFromPage{get; set;}

public void saveMyValue() {
    prefix__MySettings__c settings = prefix__MySettings__c.getInstance();
    settings.prefix__myField__c = myValueFromPage;
    upsert settings;
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!myValueFromPage}">
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveMyValue}" value="Save Input"/>
```

Comment: Can you add more information about SetupOwnerId to your answer? If a User or Profile level setting exists, the change your code makes will have no effect because you are modifying the "Default Organization Level" value.

Comment: @KeithC you're right, thanks for noticing. I've updated the setting instantiation to make it less confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code from this [site](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/07/25/allowing-any-user-to-edit-custom-settings/).User should have  Customize Application permissions then below code works

```
<apex:page controller="SuperDuperSettingController">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Name</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!setting.Name}"/>                
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
    public class SuperDuperSettingController {

    public SettingProxy setting {get; set;}

    public SuperDuperSettingController() {
        String settingId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get( 'id' );
        if (settingId != null ) {
            setting = new SettingProxy([SELECT Id, Name FROM SuperDuperSetting__c WHERE Id = :settingId]);
        } else {
            setting = new SettingProxy();
        }
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        if (setting.Id != null) {
            update setting.getSuperDuperSetting();
        } else {
            setting.insertSetting();
        }
        PageReference pr = Page.SuperDuperSetting;
        pr.getParameters().put('Id', setting.Id);
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }

    public class SettingProxy {
        public Id Id {get;set;}
        public String Name {get;set;}

        public SettingProxy(SuperDuperSetting__c sdp) {
            this.Id = sdp.Id;
            this.Name = sdp.Name;
        }

        public SettingProxy() {}

        public SuperDuperSetting__c getSuperDuperSetting() {
            return new SuperDuperSetting__c(
                Id = this.Id,
                Name = this.Name
            );
        }

        public void insertSetting() {
            SuperDuperSetting__c sdp = this.getSuperDuperSetting();
            insert sdp;
            this.Id = sdp.Id;
        }

    }
}
```